# Loading multiple `csv` files containing comma or period as decimal point

Tags: r, csv

I typically receive `csv` files from Europe and the USA. Files from Europe have a comma and files from the USA have a period as the decimal point. I would like to be able to put all of those files into a single directory and load them with one function.

Minimum working example:

```
write.table(data.frame("a" = 1.4, "b" = 2.5),  sep = ",",
        "periodFile1.csv", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(data.frame("c" = 1.4, "d" = 2.5),  sep = ",",
        "periodFile2.csv", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE)
```

I have been using separate procedures for each type of decimal point.

For a period as a decimal point I use the following:

```
periodNames <-  list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
lapply(seq_along(periodNames),
        function(x) read.csv(periodNames[x], dec = "."))
```

The following is not part of my routine procedure but is needed for the minimum working example otherwise the next load function would produce an error.

`file.remove(c("periodFile1.csv", "periodFile2.csv"))`

For a comma as a decimal point I use the following:

```
write.table(data.frame("e" = 2.7, "f" = 4.5), sep = ";", 
        "CommaFile1.csv", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(data.frame("g" = 2.7, "h" = 4.5),  sep = ";", 
        "CommaFile2.csv", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE)
commaNames <-  list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
lapply(seq_along(commaNames),
        function(x) read.csv(commaNames[x], dec = ",", sep = ";"))
```

I would like to be able to load all files into the workspace regardless of the type of decimal point. To do this, I hope to create a load function that checks for the type of decimal place and uses the appropriate load method.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `readLines` to read a few lines of each file and test the content to determine the correct delimiter. You will have to verify that this test works with your data, but I would start with something simple, like seeing if there is a semicolon in the first line of data:

```
grepl(';', line)
```

Then, use this function to read a file

```
read_csv_file <- function(file_path){
  second_line <- readLines(file_path, n=2)[2]
  if (grepl(';', second_line)){
    return(read.csv(file_path, dec=',', sep=';'))
  }else return(read.csv(file_path))
}
```

And call it like this (I simplify some of your code here too)

```
allNames <-  list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
lapply(allNames, read_csv_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have millions of files and I need one function that loads both.

Comment: Ok, I renamed 'periodNames' to 'allNames'.

Comment: I am not sure your code would work if there are `;` in a `,`-separated .csv document, because of the `grepl(';', second_line)` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that there would be one column if `;` was not a separator.

This should do it:

```
allNames <-  list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
   for (i in 1:length(allNames)){
      if(dim(read.delim(allNames[i],sep=";"))[2]==1) print(read.csv(allNames[i]))
      else print(read.csv2(allNames[i]))
    }
```

Of course you can load, combine and save the read files wherever you want instead of printing.